# Need help with 2005 Hot Springs Spa - Only heats temporarily

Tags: hot-tub

[image][image: house breaker][image: hot tub type][breakers outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERyci.jpg) ][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERyci.jpg)[[image: type]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWqjC.jpg)After reading what seems like EVERY single blog/forum/post on the internet and getting nowhere I have finally accepted my defeat and have come here to beg for your help!

I bought a house that came with a 2005 Hot Springs Vanguard spa. Everything works EXCEPT the heat. Here is what I know/have tried:

You can feel hot water coming out of the drain when the power is first turned on. This lasts about 30 minutes give or take, then back to cold

No error codes on display and heat light is on

Circuit board is not burnt up (removed everything and checked back of board as well)

Circ pump works, jets work, lights work, ozone works. Bubbles are strong from drain

Water feature works but it needs to be turned off when power is first turned on to hot tub otherwise I get the blinking red and green lights. Once tub has been on a few minutes then the water feature can be turned on and there are no blinking lights and water feature works

I have tried with and without brand new filters installed. I ran a spa cleaner through the pipes and drained and refilled to ensure any YUCK was removed

Initially I did replace the end cap on the end of the No-Fault heater because you could see it was cracked and leaking at the end of the heater. Note heat did the same thing before and after this replacement part was installed

Help! Please! I live in a rural area and can not get anybody to come out and service/ check so any help you can offer would be much appreciated. Otherwise I'm strongly considering junking this thing!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add some pictures of the control panel insides?

Comment: Also what area are you in?  I have installed several in the PNW , might have different features in different areas. I think it is a pressure switch since the heat light is still on, the pressure switch cuts the power to the element when it detects low or no flow , I have seen this before but more info is needed.

Comment: Tell me about the circuit breakers back in the service panel. There will be two panels: the house's main panel with probably a 50A; and a subpanel within sight of the spa with 2 breakers in it (possibly more).  These are all double breakers. (that's a fact; I'm just telling you that).  For each of the breakers -- **are the 2 handles factory- linked so they must throw together, or can they be thrown independently?**

Comment: Harper-Reinstate Monica I can confirm I have the setup you reference above, We turn on power at the main breaker (in the house) and then flip the 2 breakers for the tub outside (at the same time).

Comment: Pics added. I am in South Carolina. I also looked closer at these 2 wires that are connected to the heater. Could this be causing a short? Might explain why it only heats temporarily. If so, is this fixable? These essentially run in to the heater so I can't see a way to replace the entire cord. Maybe an electrician to replace the ends? I'd hate to replace the entire No-Fault heater if that is all that is causing it.

Comment: Can you post photos of the circuit breakers please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel main power or GFCI? I can tell you they aren't tripping because everything else works and I've checked for trips. I can still get pics if that helps though!

Comment: @AshleyTaylor -- both

Comment: Pics added of breakers. Thanks!